# Why doesn't this generic method accept any type?

Tags: java, generics

In the code below, when I call `getList()` I am not able to specify `<T>`. `getList<T>()` does not compile.

Instead, I may only call `getList()` - but then `<T>` is always simply `<Event>` .

Why is this?

```
class Foo
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // For the sake of a complete example - the next method has
        // my question.
        Foo f = new Foo();
        f.register(new Subscriber<MyEvent>() {
            public void handle(MyEvent event){};
        });
    }

    public <T extends Event> void register(Subscriber<T> subscriber) {

        // Below won't work. I can't specify <T>, so getList()
        // will return a HashSet<Subscriber<Event>>, to which I cannot
        // add the Subscriber<T>!

        getList().add(subscriber);

        // Why can't I call getList<T>().add(subscriber) ?

    }

    private <T extends Event> HashSet<Subscriber<T>> getList() {
        // For the sake of example, simply return a new HashSet.
        return new HashSet<Subscriber<T>>();
    }
}

interface Subscriber<T extends Event> {
    public void handle(T event);
}

interface Event { }
class MyEvent implements Event { }
```

Comment: Probably in [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Java won't accept a `<T>` as the type argument to a simple name such as `getList()`.  But it will accept it if you explicitly state `this.` when calling the method:

```
this.<T>getList().add(subscriber);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the right answer is to make `Foo` into `Foo<T extends Event>` so that when in `Foo` `T` is defined.

Otherwise, try `this.<T>getList()`. This is how this is done for statics `MyClass.<String>someMethod()`. Not sure if it will also work for an instance method. Again, the best answer is to make `Foo` generic.

Comment: Making Foo generic doesn't make sense in my case since the purpose of Foo (in the real app) is to maintain multiple lists of Subscribers to various Event types. Making the entire class generic would mean it is only possible to maintain a list of Subscribers for a single event type.

That said, I have changed the architecture around now, since it is so hard to reason about T (I don't seem to be able to call T.class, for example). A bit of a shame, since now each of my event subscribers need a little boilerplate code, but you have to experiment to learn, eh...

Comment: FYI, the reason you can't call `T.class` is `type-erasure`. At runtime all generic types are replaced with `Object`. So if you could do `T.class` all you would get back is `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

The `T` from you example is extending `Event` in both methods of `Foo` class. Well that **implicitly** means you `Foo` class is working only with `<T extends Event>` type inference. Unfortunately, your `T` is defined only at method scope. For humans all looks alright. But compiler is a bit different. Compiler doesn't believe you and it's not able to figure out implicit informations, however they are just fine, logically. You did not define your `T` at Class scope and the compiler did not figure out you are using the same type inference in both methods. So, compiler wont let you mix these method together.

So, the solution should explicitly define type inference  is for Class scope use not only for method scope.

```
class Foo<T extends Event>
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // For the sake of a complete example - the next method has
        // my question.
        Foo<MyEvent> f = new Foo<MyEvent>();
        f.register(new Subscriber<MyEvent>() {
            public void handle(MyEvent event){};
        });
    }

    public void register(Subscriber<T> subscriber) {

        // Below won't work. I can't specify <T>, so getList()
        // will return a HashSet<Subscriber<Event>>, to which I cannot
        // add the Subscriber<T>!

        getList().add(subscriber);

        // Why can't I call getList<T>().add(subscriber) ?

    }

    private HashSet<Subscriber<T>> getList() {
        // For the sake of example, simply return a new HashSet.
        return new HashSet<Subscriber<T>>();
    }

}

interface Subscriber<T extends Event> {
    public void handle(T event);
}

 class MyEvent extends Event {

}
 class Event {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to be a little more gentle with Java. This seems to work without warnings:

```
HashSet<Subscriber<T>> list = getList();
list.add(subscriber);
```